# Shuffle names of numbered files in a directory

Tags: linux, command-line, batch-rename

I have a directory of files on a Linux machine, named from 1.txt to 500.txt. They were created in order, but I want to shuffle the numbers and rename them.

ie- shuffle so 1.txt could end up 67.txt, 2.txt could end up 161.txt, 500.txt could end up 7.txt, etc.

Is there any semi-easy way to do that from the command line without spending time writing a python or bash script? Couldn't find anything in my googling that would apply.  Thanks.

Comment: So you want to randomise them? Keep the same range, swap names around?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Still want 1.txt through 500.txt, but want the actual files to be shuffled around and renamed within that number range.

I know I can do it if I use a python script or something, but before I spend time on that just wondered if there was an easier way on the command line to make that happen.

Comment: I can't think of anything that won't become quite involved. You basically need to maintain two lists and pop anything that was already a target out of the list of sources and targets to avoid losing some files.

Comment: Because the target names are the same as the source names, there is no way to do this in one step.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, that's kinda what I figured but just wanted to see if someone had a trick that I couldn't find. I'll probably just end up writing a script to do exactly what Tink said - just keep track of numbers and pop them out of the list as they get used.